# Can I store a 1D array inside a 2D array?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I store an array into a 2d array. To explain what I mean I'll use numbers.

```
a1dArray = 1,2,3
another1dArray = 4,5,6
a2dArray[1] = a1dArray
a2dArray[2] = another1dArray
```

Result:

```
a2dArray[1,0] = 1
a2dArray[1,1] = 2
a2dArray[1,2] = 3
a2dArray[2,0] = 4
a2dArray[2,1] = 5
a2dArray[2,3] = 6
```

---

Here is how I want to do it in my code
animations is the 2d array and the function returns a 1d array

```
Animation [index] animations = part.FindModelAnimators(animationName)
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to use an array of arrays instead - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx

Comment: Multidimensional/jagged arrays are one of the areas where there are quite difference syntaxes and possibilities between different C-like languages. So, if you have a lot of experience with, say, C++, you still have to look this  one up in C#.

Answer (score 4):

Declare `a2dArray` as `int[n][]` rather than `int[n, m]`. (`n` and `m` are any integers you care to use as the length of your array.) You'll then be able to jam an entire `int[]` array into it, just like in your example. [Read more on jagged arrays at MSDN.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx)

Reading from the array will then be done like `int oneVal = a2dArray[n][m]`.

Comment: Use a List<>.  A two dimensional array is List<List<object>>.  The object can also be a list.

Comment: @jdweng: A list is not the same as an array. For example, you can expect that it is a fast operation to add an element to the end of a list, but that is not an array method ("IList.Add: Calling this method always throws a NotSupportedException exception.") and the normal way to do that would involve creating a new larger array, copying the old array over, which may be much slower. A jagged array is closer to a List<List<Object>> but it is not the same, and a rectangular array is quite different.

Comment: Douglas : A list is an array with added functionality.  You can do everything with a list that you can do with an array.  I should of said a List<List<object>> is a two dimensional array (instead I said it backwards).